# Jboss Fuse Camel AriesXATransaction Mybatis oracle javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback

Tags: oracle, apache-camel, jbossfuse, spring-mybatis, aries

```
Jboss Fuse Aries XA transactions issue. XA Datasource is setup using Aries-XA auto enlistment.
```

**Blueprint-xml for exposing datasource**

```
    <service interface="javax.sql.XADataSource" ref="oracle-XA-DB">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="datasource.name" value="oracleXADB" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.name" value="oracle-XA-DB" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.username" value="${datasource.user}" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.password" value="${datasource.password}" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.pooling" value="true" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.poolMinSize" value="0" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.poolMaxSize" value="10" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.exceptionSorter" value="known" />
            <entry key="aries.xa.transaction" value="none" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>

This datasource exposed is retrieved using mybatis-component to execute the database operations. The XA commit, roll-backs are working fine for the initial few transactions. Later, the entire bundles dependent upon the datasource fails with the following exception. Once, the bundles are restarted, the services are working fine, but only for a limited time.
```

**StackTrace**
    org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage|Method Name : autoSave|Log Data : On Exception Error MSG|Exception Message :JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback|Exception StackTrace :org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
            at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1015)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
            at org.apache.aries.transaction.internal.AriesPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AriesPlatformTransactionManager.java:76)
            at Proxya177c340_4c14_44ff_9bff_2753cc771417.commit(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:148)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:174)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:134)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:103)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:112)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:55)
            at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProducer.process(DirectVmProducer.java:55)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
            at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfRsInvoker.java:93)
            at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsInvoker.performInvocation(CxfRsInvoker.java:68)
            at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:97)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:200)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:99)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
            at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
            at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
            at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)
            at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
            at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
            at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
            at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:272)
            at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
            at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1012)
            ... 72 more
    Caused by: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1101)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:237)
            at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.WrapperNamedXAResource.start(WrapperNamedXAResource.java:111)
            at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:209)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.TransactionEnlistingInterceptor.getConnection(TransactionEnlistingInterceptor.java:60)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.TransactionCachingInterceptor.getConnection(TransactionCachingInterceptor.java:101)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.ConnectionHandleInterceptor.getConnection(ConnectionHandleInterceptor.java:43)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.TCCLInterceptor.getConnection(TCCLInterceptor.java:39)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.ConnectionTrackingInterceptor.getConnection(ConnectionTrackingInterceptor.java:66)
            at org.apache.geronimo.connector.outbound.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:81)
            at org.tranql.connector.jdbc.TranqlDataSource.getConnection(TranqlDataSource.java:62)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
            at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:81)
            at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:67)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.getConnection(BaseExecutor.java:279)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:72)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:59)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator.processGeneratedKeys(SelectKeyGenerator.java:66)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.SelectKeyGenerator.processBefore(SelectKeyGenerator.java:46)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.generateKeys(BaseStatementHandler.java:130)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.BaseStatementHandler.(BaseStatementHandler.java:63)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.(PreparedStatementHandler.java:39)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.(RoutingStatementHandler.java:45)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.newStatementHandler(Configuration.java:468)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:46)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105)
            at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152)
            at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor701.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.insert(Unknown Source)
            at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:240)
            at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)
            at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.insertAutoSaveData(Unknown Source)
            at com.scb.s2b.entity.common.service.autosavedata.dao.AutoSaveDataServiceDAO.insertAutoSaveData(AutoSaveDataServiceDAO.java:46)
            at com.scb.s2b.entity.common.service.autosavedata.AutoSaveDataServiceImpl.create(AutoSaveDataServiceImpl.java:101)
            at Proxy35e8703c_fb57_4678_af6c_7d0e2a0c7f6b.create(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor700.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:408)
            at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:279)
            at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:252)
            at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:171)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:166)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:113)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor.process(TryProcessor.java:84)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
            at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:329)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler.process(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:166)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:218)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:99)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:112)
            at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
            at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:218)
            at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:181)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:33)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
            ... 67 more